# Paypal checkout render button not same

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using paypal checkout.js smart button . I just tried use below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

When i compile on code open editor it show
[image]

On my site it show
[image]

I dont know which reason make difference that ? I only want it show Debit or Credit Card button

Comment: Probably due to what is explained under https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/#which-buttons-will-i-see

Comment: @04FS Thank for reply , Can I custom for preventing show dynamically ?